# Avoid No virtual method registerAnimationCallback with Glide and Proguard minification

Tags: android, proguard, android-glide, android-proguard

We have a custom library (com.example.mylib) being included as an external dependency by our app (com.example.myapp). Our library in turn uses [Glide GIF handling](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library. Also, our library is minified by Proguard.

At runtime our app crashes with the following logcat:

```
2019-04-23 15:47:46.642 11066-11066/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 11066
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method registerAnimationCallback(Landroid/support/graphics/drawable/Animatable2Compat$AnimationCallback;)V in class Lcom/bumptech/glide/load/resource/gif/GifDrawable; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gif.GifDrawable' appears in /data/app/com.example.myapp-C3jnO5_79zyarj8XR40khQ==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
        at com.example.mylib.MyComponent$1.onResourceReady(SourceFile:4)
        at com.example.mylib.MyComponent$1.onResourceReady(SourceFile:1)
        at com.bumptech.glide.request.SingleRequest.onResourceReady(SingleRequest.java:574)
        at com.bumptech.glide.request.SingleRequest.onResourceReady(SingleRequest.java:549)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineJob.handleResultOnMainThread(EngineJob.java:218)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineJob$MainThreadCallback.handleMessage(EngineJob.java:324)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I cannot figure out why `GifDrawable.registerAnimationCallback(...)` method is obfuscated.

I think we followed all suggested proguard/Glide rules:

- custom class extending `LibraryGlideModule`
- build dependencies like `com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0`, `com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0`, `com.zlc.glide:webpdecoder:0.0.8.4.7.1`
- Glide-specific Proguard rules copied from [official readme](https://github.com/bumptech/glide#proguard)

I can see automatically generated Glide-files under `build\` directory. Also, inspecting generated JAR file under `packaged-classes\`, I cannot see anything suspicious: only our custom public components are kept in clear, other custom private/anonymous/etc. components are minified.

Even if it should not make a lot of sense in building our library, I also kept unminified the following, with no luck:

```
# our custom, anonymous RequestListeners
-keep class * implements com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestListener {
    public *;
}

# GifDrawable itself by Glide
-keep class com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gif.GifDrawable {
    public *;
}
```

For those not used to Glide or wondering what's the interesting bit of code, here it is:

```
Glide.with(myContext)
    .asGif()
    .load(myResourceId)
    .listener(new RequestListener<GifDrawable>() {

        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(GifDrawable resource,
                                       Object model,
                                       Target<GifDrawable> target,
                                       DataSource dataSource,
                                       boolean isFirstResource) {
            myReadyGif = resource;
            resource.setLoopCount(1);
            resource.registerAnimationCallback(
                new Animatable2Compat.AnimationCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Drawable drawable) {
                        super.onAnimationEnd(drawable);
                        // do something
                    }
                });
            return false;
        }

        //...
    })
    .into(myViewTarget);
```

Being `registerAnimationCallback` a relatively new addition to Glide library, I'm wondering if this issue has to do with the library itself. Not sure yet what it means, but the preceding `setLoopCount(...)` method invocation causes no issue.

Comment: Seeing that `registerAnimationCallback` belongs to `android.support.graphics.drawable.Animatable2Compat`, I also tried explicitly adding `implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0' as a dependency in myapp build, with no luck.
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this was a total copy/paste error from us of a *detail* when we extracted code & configuration from the app to create a dedicated library module:

while app build.gradle included Glide dependency as:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
```

when the same is ported to the library, it should be turned to:

```
api 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
```

The counter-proof was that, with the copy/paste error still in place, it was enough to re-add the dependency to the app as well, and the runtime error was gone.